# Object instance as a member of a list --> Is this "pythonic"? Is this lege artis?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, design-patterns

I like to have your opinion or a suggestion to this code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


# Defines the class (Element) that will be used in the Container
class Element:
    def __init__(self, address):
        # The address is the identifier for this element
        self._address = int(address)

    def theaddress(self):
        # Getter for the address
        return self._address

    def __eq__(self, other):
        # This function will be called if we like to check if this instanse is already a
        # member of the container instance
        print("A __eq__ called: %r == %r ?" % (self, other))
        return self._address == other._address


# Defines the class (Container) which holds n instances of Element class
class Container:
    def __init__(self):
        # Basically it is a list
        self._listcontainers = list()

    # If we like to append a new element instance, we have to check if new one is already available
    # with the same address. So we like to never had the same address twice or more times!
    def appendcontainer(self, possibleElement: Element = Element(1)):
        # Calls the __eq__ element of the Element class to check if this one (with exactly this address) is already present
        if possibleElement in self._listcontainers:
            # If the possibleElement is in the container list
            print('Address %i of this element %s is already existing.' % (possibleElement.theaddress(), possibleElement))
            return False
        else:
            # If possobleElement is new append it to the containerlist
            self._listcontainers.append(possibleElement)
            print('Added element: %s with address: %i' % (possibleElement, possibleElement.theaddress()))
            return True

    # Returns the available elements in the containers
    def lengthcontainers(self):
        return len(self._listcontainers)


def main():
    # List of containers
    myContainer = Container()

    # New element with address 1
    newElement1 = Element(1)
    myContainer.appendcontainer(newElement1)

    # New element with address 2
    newElement2 = Element(2)
    myContainer.appendcontainer(newElement2)

    # New element with address xyz
    newElement3 = Element(2) # You can play with the addresses...
    myContainer.appendcontainer(newElement3)

    print('Available elements: %i' % myContainer.lengthcontainers())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

### Now:

- I have a class Element which represents an abstraction of some data. It will contain some logic by itself as private methods too...
- I have a class (Container in this example) which holds n element instances.
- I need to prevent the appending of an element with the same properties. In this example - the same address.

### Questions:

- I like to know if this is state of the art for doing the identification of an element?
- Maybe is there a better way for doing this in Python 3?
- Especially the `__eq__` function is very interesting for me. Because, `_address` should be a private variable and I get a warning at `other._address` --> "Access to protected member _address of a class...". Do I have to consider something here?

Any opinion or suggestion will be very helpful for me. Actually I'm doing only prototyping, but it should be the basic for an real project which holds some data in this case.

Comment: This would maybe be better suited to be asked in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can you use a `set()` instead? A set holds unique elements.

Comment: `Container` could be replaced by `set()`, `Element` could be replaced by `namedtuple`. IMO using ubiquitous data structures and patterns makes code easier to read and maintain.

Comment: @ruohola Yes you are right. I don’t know this forum. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that magic methods (like `__eq__`, `__le__`, etc.) are allowed (in terms of code style) to use protected members of `other` objects, so I would ignore the warning.

As for the appending, I would suggest using `set` instead of `list` if it is possible. Storing only different elements is the work for the `set` and you don't need to check the presence of the Element, `set` would do it for you. Don't forget to implement `__hash__` method for your `Element` class:

```
class Element:
    ...

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self._address)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self._address == other._address
```

Comment: Great it works. But if I add an element which is already in the set, I do not get a return value (False)? Is this correct?

Comment: Correct. So if you need it to return False you can check if the element in the set beforehand manually. In Python `set` is implemented as HashSet, so this check will be in O(1).